# ¿Cómo abrir una imagen en un panel?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy tratando de recrear un programa estilo paint y estoy teniendo un problema al abrir imágenes. Quiero que haya un opción que sea "abrir" que te permita (como su nombre lo dice) abrir una imagen y plasmarla en un componente jPanel. Pero que lo haga como paint lo hace, que abra el archivo, no que lo dibuje (quizá sea la única forma de hacerlo, no estoy seguro) Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    JFileChooser navegador = new JFileChooser();
    if (navegador.showOpenDialog(null) == 0) {
        try {
            BufferedImage imagenAbrir = ImageIO.read(navegador.getSelectedFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ocurriò un error al abrir la imàgen");
        }
    }
```

Mi plan es pasar esa imagen a un JPanel, pero no sé como hacerlo. Lo intenté de la siguiente forma, pero no funcionó:

```
    JFileChooser navegador = new JFileChooser();
    if (navegador.showOpenDialog(null) == 0) {
        try {
            BufferedImage imagenAbrir = ImageIO.read(navegador.getSelectedFile());
            Graphics g = imagenAbrir.getGraphics();
            lienzo.paint(g);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ocurriò un error al abrir la imàgen");
        }
    }
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? No sé si es posible no utilizar el método drawImage(), porque tengo una opción que permite hacer eso, dibujar las imagenes. No sé si me doy a entender.

Por cierto, lienzo es el nombre de mi JPanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un Jlabel en tu Jpanel secundario (lienzo) en el que a traves del metodo que recoge el archivo seleccionado del JfileChooser

```
File imagenSeleccionada = navegador.getSelectedFile()
```

Puedes coger la ruta de esa imagen y ponersela al JLabel que creamos antes

```
nombreLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(.getAbsolutePath());
```

Ahora lo unico que faltaría es añadir ese jlabel al JPanel (lienzo)

```
lienzo.add(nombreLabel)
```

Con eso debería de verse la imagen en el Jframe
Un saludo